# SQL - insert a number for another number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add to an SQL statement the ability to output a number if another number is found in a column. Basically, map a number to a given value so we can calculate commissions inside of Excel. We have a value called PaymentMethodID that declares what kind of payment it was. Cash (1), check (2), credit card (3) or PayPal (4). Sales reps commissions change based on what kind of payment was used, so now we hand edit the spreadsheets to make the reports.

I would like to create a column called "Commission %" that outputs a decimal based on what is found in PaymentMethodID.

Example

```
   SalesRep   OrderValue    PaymentMethodID    Commission %
   Sara       100.00        1                  15%
   Sara       80.00         2                  15%
   Sara       350.00        1                  15%
   Sara       200.00        3                  12.5%
```

How can I create the "Commissions %" column and have the PaymentMethodID's mapped to a percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CASE statement. Something like this:

```
SELECT
        SalesRep,
        OrderValue,
        PaymentMethodID,
        CASE
            WHEN PaymentMethodID = 1 THEN 15.00
            WHEN PaymentMethodID = 2 THEN 15.00
            WHEN PaymentMethodID = 3 THEN 12.50
        END as CommisionPercent
FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 6):

The clean way to do this, is to create a `PaymentMethods` table containing the commission (or extending your `PaymentMethods` table, if you already have one).

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE PaymentMethods (
  PaymentMethodID INT NOT NULL,
  CommissionPerc FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO PaymentMethods VALUES
  (1,15), (2,15), (3,12.5);
```

Then simply join the table, similar to

```
SELECT 
  Sales.SalesRep, 
  Sales.OrderValue
  Sales.PaymentMethodID,
  PaymentMethods.CommissionPerc
FROM
  Sales
  INNER JOIN PaymentMethods ON Sales.PaymentMethodID=PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodID
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot create tables. =(